# Button Filter view problem in User Profile

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, profile-page, views

I clicked on the Views button (other buttons have same problem) and got the following instead of the usual list (which it starts out in):

[image]

and yes, besides the formatting problems, the "Q" is actually cut off.

It's now gone away, so I can't tell what went wrong, but something did.

Using Firefox 3.6.9.

Comment: Looks like the page might have loaded w/o CSS? This happens to me several times a week on SO. One tap at `F5` has always solved the problem.

Comment: @Peter, do you think it's a Firefox bug?

Comment: No, I think that the site just doesn't "serve" the CSS sometimes. I use Chrome, and it happens to me too.

Comment: this CAN happen if you're getting blocked for excessive network requests.

Comment: @Peter: I am using Opera, and lately, this happens to me every now and then on many SE sites. However, on every single one of those occasions so far, the CSS eventually *was* loaded — sometimes a few seconds later, sometimes faster. I am not sure whether it's just the server load, or whether Opera resorts to black magic and, say, re-sends a failed request or falls back to cached CSS. Anyway, this started to happen only relatively recently.

Answer (score 1):

this CAN happen if you're getting blocked for excessive network requests.

Otherwise, it remains no-repro.