# Mobile site highlighting someone elses favourite tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, tag-watching

When viewing Server Fault on my iPhone, I'm seeing [some questions highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUuE2.png) as if they are my favourite tags, but... they're not.

I only have one favourite tag, [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell). This seems to be showing [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) and [windows-server-2008](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008)

Here's another example, on Meta:

- [Mobile view, with unexpected highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqgez.png)
- [Normal view, with no highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLRC9.png)

Switching back to the mobile view fixed the problem briefly in this case, but then the highlighting came back.

The page appears to be coming back with the right *user* information, suggesting the problem is not inappropriate caching at the ISP level...

[image: correct user ID for Tim Stone in page]

...despite [incorrect highlighting being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhyex.png) due to someone else's (or a random) list of favorite tags being specified later on in the page:

[image: invalid list of tags from same page]

Comment: I've had this happen before too. I always thought it was inferring what to highlight based on what I had been looking at, but I'd only expect that to happen if you didn't have any favourite tags.

Comment: which page were you on?

Comment: @NickCraver - homepage. Straight bookmark to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: You're not logged into someone else's account perchance, are you? ;-)

Comment: Not unless it's my wifes, but I don't think she uses Stack Exchange ;) Interesting fact - I just went back to check that and now the highlighting has gone back to normal.

Comment: Worth noting that I've only ever been able to reproduce this while on 3G, for whatever reason. Might just be circumstantial since I'm usually on an actual computer when I'm within wifi range.

Comment: @TimStone - I've certainly had it on WiFi. I tend not to use the 3G that much...

Comment: Yeah, I realised even in your screenshot you're on wifi. I'd expect it was some intermediary caching something it wasn't supposed to, but I doubt that'd make sense in your case...so I'm still at a loss. Certainly still happening, though.

Comment: Happened to me as well (home wifi). Before I had favorited `[moderator*]` on MSO, the mobile site would randomly decide that I really liked one of the compulsory tags (not necessarily `[discussion]`, which has always been my best tag on MSO)

Comment: I've had this happen on several occasions on mobile. It seems to be totally arbitrary and is generally fixed by a refresh.

Comment: Still, despite being on Wifi, this *might* be a provider [caching things it should not cache](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86033/hijacked-session-signed-in-as-someone-else/86041#86041). But then one would also see it on the regular site. For @Tim, if you're on 3G then ensure your mobile provider is not caching stuff from someone else...? Some are even known [to add JavaScript to your page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120356/im-unable-to-join-chat-in-safari-on-my-iphone-when-on-my-mobile-network-o2/120369#120369) (or your phone number to request headers)...

Comment: @Arjan On second thought it's unlikely (or impossible) that the problem is an intermediary cache, because I have another screenshot from the same period where my user information in the mobile drop-down was correct, and that's included in the original page...so if I was getting someone else's page from my ISP I should have gotten the wrong gravatar and such too.

Comment: I quickly tested, @Tim, and it seems opening that dropdown invokes new requests before showing the info. I wouldn't be surprised that a provider would not have cached that for other users **yet**, hence requesting the correct data for you... That said: as for others it's happening on Wifi (but probably not on the regular site for that same Wifi), caching by a provider is not likely here. Too bad the mobile page does not show some username or reputation without first expanding the menu.

Comment: @Arjan It requests the contents of the inbox, but not the user information. That's just hidden on page load, and shown when you click the arrow.

Comment: Ah, @Tim, then you're right -- and can sleep at night again ;-)

Comment: I was able to reproduce on wifi, and (now that I have a MacBook to do so with) inspect the page source using the Safari remote debugger. I added the relevant details into the question.

Comment: @TimStone thanks, we see the issue.  Part of the page (including that script block beside the list) is cached aside from output cache...it's not a trivial fix but I'll see how to best move that outside inner-view cache.

Answer (score 3):

A fix has been deployed on meta.se and will be on the network in the next deployment.

As with all caching bugs, community verification is important. Can anyone replicate?

Comment: Since the iOS app was released I haven't used the mobile site. I will have to go back to using it for a while :)