# Favourite tag highlighting gone on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

Questions with my favourite tags used to be highlighted on the mobile site, and indeed still are on the full site. Now, they're all the same colour. Can this be fixed?

I'm using Safari on iPhone, iOS 7.1, and the specific site I'm talking about is stack overflow - I don't have favourite tags on other SE sites.

It appears to only affect the front page - the questions page or a specific tag view page show the highlighting fine. However, it's the front page where it's important!

Mobile view:

[image]

Vs web:

[image]

Comment: I got this reproduced too. Both my active sites, Meta and SO, are affected.

Comment: I see the same on iPhone using chrome. And I agree this is really annoying.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson not annoying enough, apparently

Comment: Actually I am beyond the annoying part. I don't use the phone to keep an eye out for interesting questions anymore. The stackexchange app does not handle favorite tags either so currently there is no way to keep up with questions using the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks. A [recent bugfix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128047/mobile-site-highlighting-someone-elses-favourite-tags) worked correctly on most question lists, but not on the homepage.