# Chat not loading on iOS 5.1

Tags: support, chat, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm unable to join chat in Safari on my iPhone when on my mobile network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120356/im-unable-to-join-chat-in-safari-on-my-iphone-when-on-my-mobile-network)

I can't seem to load the chat (both mobile and desktop UI) on my iPhone 4 running iOS 5.1. The console gives these errors:

[image: mobile safari error console with two error messages]

EDIT: I tried it using my school's wi-fi and it loaded correctly, suggesting that it is O2. But when I tried it on my brother's iPhone 3G (iOS 4.2.1) that is also on O2, it worked fine. And his cellular data settings are identical to mine.

Comment: Hmm, unable to reproduce here. Maybe there's a bad version of master-chat.js cached either on your device or at your service provider?

Comment: I think there is some kind of compression on o2's side because once before stackoverflow.com wouldn't load any CSS, because the site used a strange character or something.

Comment: Norepro iPad (whatever the latest iOS is--iirc 5.2)

Comment: @Tim stone, thanks but the issue has been Marked as accepted and it isn't. It is not just a problem with O2, as problems only ever occur with stackexchange sites and it works fine on my brothers phone.

Comment: @manishearth. The latest iOS is 5.1, and are you using o2's cell connection?

Comment: @Jonathan.: Nope. Wifi. Yeah, must be a filtering problem.

Comment: @manisearth, in conjunction with a problem on stackexchange because it works on my brothers and I don't have any problem anywhere else.