# Log-in bug wth chat

Tags: support, chat

I log into my account and click on chat and it redirects me to chat yet logged in as a different user. There is no way to get out of the user. When I go to another site it displays and uses the proper account but the second I try to chat it goes back to the other account. Really annoying.

Comment: There are no details here that would allow anyone to reproduce this problem (or even to sufficiently describe it). Is the "different user" a different one of your own accounts? Is it someone else's? What specific sites are you talking about (since you specify "another site" but post on the StackOverflow meta site)?

Comment: Someone elses account. Not one of my accounts. I am talking about ANY site but chat.

Comment: Scratch that if I go from stack overflow to chat it works but not from super user to chat.

Comment: Shared computer? (Do you know that other user?) Shared IP address? Which internet provider? (Yes, some [mess up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120356/im-unable-to-join-chat-in-safari-on-my-iphone-when-on-my-mobile-network-o2/120369#120369), [big time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86033/hijacked-session-signed-in-as-someone-else/86041#86041).)

Comment: Shared computer. And I don't think I know the user. At least I don't recognize the name. All the accounts I remember making didn't last long but were properly named.

Comment: It does work from this other computer however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, though it's admittedly not <s>very</s> at all discoverable: https://chat.stackexchange.com/logout.

Comment: Thank you for that. Also we need to lower the response limit. I can't say simple responses like Thank you. Or a good deal of others because of the character limit.,