# AJAXy control buttons on user profile page can break

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incomplete pages when browsing questions and answers in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74119/incomplete-pages-when-browsing-questions-and-answers-in-my-profile)

The question below was originally posted to Meta Server Fault and after several people could reproduce it as a bug it was suggested that I move it here to get more eyeballs on it.  The original question is http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1063/ajaxy-control-buttons-on-user-profile-page-can-break.

In looking at suggested questions when I typed the in the title on meta.SO, I have the following comments:

This is not a duplicate of these questions (though they are probably semi-related):

- [Implement ajax back button support in the user page, paging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53635/implement-ajax-back-button-support-in-the-user-page-paging-closed)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61331/clicking-the-back-button-after-visiting-a-user-profile-from-the-users-page-resets

My bug is probably a root-cause dupe for the following.  I'm filing this as a new bug because it includes steps to reproduce and I already have it typed up.

- [Button Filter view problem in User Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64386/button-filter-view-problem-in-user-profile)

Thanks

---

In Chrome 8.0.552.224 on Windows 7, I found a bug in which I receive what looks to me like the raw, unformatted output of an AJAX call instead of having that output incorporated in the page correctly.  I seem to be able to reproduce it at will in Chrome.  I was going to say that Firefox 3.6.13 didn't have the same problem, but I banged on it some more and recreated it there too.

Here's what my page looks like when I follow the steps below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetmore.org](http://jetmore.org/john/misc/error.png))</sub>

Here are the steps to reproduce in Chrome:

- Load serverfault.com
- Click on my username at the top to load my profile
- Scroll down to "Answers" section
- Click on any of the "answers" page numbers to to go any page but #1 (so, click "2" or "next")
- Click on any of the answers to load that question page in the same tab
- Click the back button to return from the question page to the profile page
- Scroll back down to the "answers" page numbers again
- Click a different page number
- Boom, all the data that should be loaded in the answers section, but in a new page, not incorporated in the profile page.

These are steps to reproduce in Firefox (this works in Chrome too and is actually a simpler way to reproduce, but I'm leaving the Chrome steps because it's how I found the problem originally which might be useful reference):

- Load serverfault.com
- Click my username to load profile page
- Scroll to answers
- Click one of the numbers to go to a different page of answers (2, for instance)
- <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload the page
- Scroll back down and click another answer page index number (2 again will work)
- And again, what appears to be the AJAX response rather than the page with the response incorporated into it.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of this bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74119/incomplete-pages-when-browsing-questions-and-answers-in-my-profile

Comment: Aye, looks the same as that report. Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70335/links-on-user-page-are-assembled-to-the-wrong-destination

Comment: This is fixed now (or rather, it will be in the next build).